# Saving a child object value via parent razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

hi how can i get child (contained) value to save correctly in edit view of parent?  The value shows up correctly but won't save?

```
    @model MVC3.Models.A

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bs.First().Val)

    public  class A
    {
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }

    public  class B
    {
        public int Val { get; set; }
        public virtual A A { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer would be to refer to the child object using array notation (of course, assuming `Children` is something that implements `IList`):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Children[0].Val)
```

If you intend to provide editors for all of the `Children` though, it would be best to define an editor template for that type and use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Children)` instead of displaying editors for each element in the collection using a loop.

**Edit:** Corrected `ICollection` instead of `IList` error.

**Update:**

If your collection only implements `ICollection` (and thus is not indexable), then you should consider using a ViewModel (exposing an `IList`) instead of the Model you currently use, to make the above valid.

If this is not an option, then you could consider this hack:

```
// essentially creating the correct name manually
@Html.TextBox(Html.NameFor(m => m.Children) + "[0].Val",
              model.Children.First().Val)
```

Of course this loses you support for automatically utilizing any editor template you may have, but this might not be a problem in your case (especially considering `Val` sounds like a simple type).

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! Originally I will iterate through list to display all Bs and allow edit but I just want to get one to save.  I try [0] syntax and I get "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ICollection<Child>'.

Comment: I have updated my post illustrating my two objects.  My question is can you post example code of how to get the [] syntax working?  I would rather not hack it but I an very new to mvc3/c#/.net.

Comment: @Mariah: What is `MVC3.Models.Parent`? To put the non-hacky solution in other words, create another class `MVC3.ViewModels.Parent` that's just like `MVC3.Models.Parent` (and can be easily initialized from one such model) that exposes an `IList` instead of an `ICollection`.

Comment: @ Jon, sorry Parent should be A (class A).  Just updated the post.  Do you have any example code?  This is for an Edit operation so the B collection already exists. What I'm not sure about is in the controller.  I definitely get the new view model (containing the IList, etc,) but it's on the Edit action httppost where I would have to assign back to the data model (models.parent as well as assign B's that already exist) then save the changes.  I keep getting errors that the model has changed and cannot be saved, etc,.  Sorry I'm a very new to this stuff.